# How do I cause my second cartographer to have different trades than my first one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my world, I made a cartographer, and maxed it. My problem is if I make an another cartographer, the trades are the same as the other (the price is too). What can I do now, to get new trades?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't bought anything from them, meaning their experience bar is 0, you can switch a villagers profession by creating a workstation for a *different* profession, and then tearing down the workstation they had. Make sure there are no other open workstations of the cartography profession available for them to use.

As long as they have not gained experience or levels, they will eventually give up the profession and switch. Now do the same thing **again** but instead of any other workstation, put back the cartography station and they will become a cartographer again and the things you can buy from them will be rerolled.

Bear in mind, you can essentially only roll their first tier purchases so even if you max the second cartographer after trolling, there is still a chance that all the later purchase tiers might be the same.

Also, once a villager gains experience with a profession, its locked and cant be changed with the above method.

From [villager minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager):

> A job site block can be claimed only if it is unclaimed and within a
> village boundary with at least 1 bed. Removal of a claimed job site
> block causes the owner to switch to another profession or become
> unemployed, provided that the villager has no prior trades with the
> player. If the villager has prior trades, it keeps its profession and
> claims a new job site block that matches its profession if one is
> available. So, once a player trades with a villager, the villager
> keeps its profession forever.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want a second cartographer, to get more cartography trade options:

**Have you levelled up your second cartographer?**

Take a look at the [table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#Cartographer) of cartographer trades. The cartographer will pick two additional trades with each level it gains, from one to five, to a maximum of 10 trades. Each trade option it makes has a minimum level requirement.

As a novice cartographer (the new cartographer) has only two trades available to it, it will always offer those two trades.

An apprentice has only four options available to it, so again always has the same offers. Journeymen only have six, so again the options will be fixed.

But, once a cartographer becomes an Expert or master, it will give you four more options out of 17,17,18,18. That means it has `17 * 16 * 16 * 15 = 65,280`  choices. In other words, there are 65,280 unique cartographers out there.

**But if you did already level it...**

You may have had some really bad luck?

Comment: I completely forgot that cartographers only have 2 possible trades at base level. You're right that my method won't have any impact with respect to cartographers.